# Selecting from two tables in sql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, query-optimization

i post this question because i really can't find a solution, i spent a day searching how to do this but i can't make it work. that's also because i'm new to sql and i need some help.

**Situation :**
I have a database with 3 tables : Orders, Producs, Buys. In my C#/.NET application i need to display all products from one order, first here is the tables structure.

```
TABLE orders
    int id
    int Totalprice

Table products
    int id
    string name
    ...

Table buys
    int id
    int price
    int quantity
    int orderId
    int productId
```

Also, a buy can have many products and have 1 order, and an order can have many buys.

**What i'm doing in my application :**

In my C#/.NET application, this is what i do :

```
SELECT * FROM buys WHERE orderid=listview.selecteditem.orderid;
```

i store this results in a list and after this:

```
foreach(item in buys)//buys is the list<buys> stored from the previous query
{
        SELECT * FROM products WHERE productid = item.productId;
}
```

**NOTE :**
this is only a pseudo code, because i didn't start coding yet.

**The problem :**
this code is working for me, but it's a bit slow and need to perform two queries to get the expected result. i need a way to do this in one sql query. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should look into `Join`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM buys b
JOIN orders o 
ON o.id = b.orderId
JOIN products p
ON b.id = o.productId
```

Note also that is good practice to specify the fields instead of using `*`.

As Michael suggested, you may want also to look at [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) for better query performance.

Comment: That is also a possible improvement.

Comment: thnaks @EndeNeu actually i got to modify the answer so it can fit with my needs, i suggusted the edit, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Like ende said, you probably want to join. Take a look at this to see which join you should do: [Visual Representation of Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)